# How do I deobfuscate Proguard in Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to integrate Firebase Crashlytics into my current project in Android Studio 3.1.4. The first time I forced a FirebaseCrash.report, I got this in my logcat:

```
08-10 07:25:25.114 16661-16718/com.example.android.twlistsales E/FirebaseCrash: Failed to initialize crash reporting
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzcaq;
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:207)
    at com.google.firebase.crash.zze.run(Unknown Source:6)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzcaq;
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdzp.<clinit>(Unknown Source:8)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdzp.initialize(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.google.firebase.crash.zzc.zzbsq(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.firebase.crash.zzd.call(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcaq" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.twlistsales-fs1zdAnDopYdjq5hyiS8pw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.twlistsales-fs1zdAnDopYdjq5hyiS8pw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.twlistsales-fs1zdAnDopYdjq5hyiS8pw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.twlistsales-fs1zdAnDopYdjq5hyiS8pw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.twlistsales-fs1zdAnDopYdjq5hyiS8pw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.twlistsales-fs1zdAnDopYdjq5hyiS8pw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.twlistsales-fs1zdAnDopYdjq5hyiS8pw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.twlistsales-fs1zdAnDopYdjq5hyiS8pw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.twlistsales-fs1zdAnDopYdjq5hyiS8pw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.twlistsales-fs1zdAnDopYdjq5hyiS8pw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.twlistsales-fs1zdAnDopYdjq5hyiS8pw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.twlistsales-fs1zdAnDopYdjq5hyiS8pw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.twlistsales-fs1zdAnDopYdjq5hyiS8pw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.android.twlistsales-fs1zdAnDopYdjq5hyiS8pw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdzp.<clinit>(Unknown Source:8) 
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdzp.initialize(Unknown Source:0) 
    at com.google.firebase.crash.zzc.zzbsq(Unknown Source:2) 
    at com.google.firebase.crash.zzd.call(Unknown Source:2) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64) /data/app/com.example.android.twlistsales-fs1zdAnDopYdjq5hyiS8pw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
    at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:36)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:678)
```

Then this:

```
08-10 07:25:25.115 16661-16718/com.example.android.twlistsales E/FirebaseCrash:     at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:711)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:944)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2303)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5943)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Then this:

```
08-10 07:25:25.117 16661-16719/com.example.android.twlistsales E/FirebaseCrash: Failed waiting for crash api to load.
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1063)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1352)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:278)
    at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.zzbsk(Unknown Source:6)
    at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.zza(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.google.firebase.crash.zza.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

And finally this, which is the error that I forced:

```
08-10 07:25:25.907 16661-16722/com.example.android.twlistsales E/**ListSales - GetSales - doInBackground(): Attempt to get sales data from database failed due to JSON Exception
org.json.JSONException: Value Foo<br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
    at com.example.android.twlistsales.ListSales$GetSales.doInBackground(ListSales.java:604)
    at com.example.android.twlistsales.ListSales$GetSales.doInBackground(ListSales.java:555)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Does anyone know what is happening here? I'm new to Firebase and don't know my way around.

I'm guessing the problem relates to the instructions that I see when I click on Tools/Firebase/Crash Reporting, specifically step 5. It tells me to deobfuscate Proguard by adding this to my gradle files.

```
debug {
minifyEnabled true proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't tell me WHICH gradle file or WHERE in that file to put this code. Can someone enlighten me? Also, how could I send a request to the Android Studio people to kindly clarify these instructions so the next person along doesn't have the exact same problem?

I'm new to both Android Studio and Gradle so the correct place to put this code is not remotely obvious to me the way it might be to a developer more experienced in this environment. I'm guessing it goes into the app-level Gradle.build but I'm not sure if it's within the android{} group of parameters or whether it is between android{} and dependecies{}. I could spend hours figuring this out by trial and error....

Answer (score 0):

Assumuning you want to obfuscate your code only in the release verion of your app (which is the most common case), the lines

```
debug {
  minifyEnabled true 
  proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

should be included in

```
android{
  buildTypes {
    release {
         <here>
    }
  }
}
```

inside your app's level build.gradle file.

However, by looking at your stack trace, it seems that you have a  missing dependency problem you should take care of before obfuscating your code (which is optional, especially if you're not much experienced).